# Haskell Gloss Particle Effects

Tags: haskell, particle-system, particles, gloss

How to create particle effects in Haskell using the Gloss library? (e.g. to show an explosion)

If anyone could help me out a bit on how this is done it'd be much appreciated.

Best Regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: I'm currently Learning gloss. If I figure it out, I'll post. I haven't made an animated Picture yet, but basically how it would work is you have a picture representing a particle (just a randomly generated circle), and some kind of counter in your main environment. Every "tick" advances the counter, and the current value of the counter decides how the Picture is displayed (it's size, color, whether or not it still active...). The specifics obviously depend on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The comment on the question does a good job of providing a high-level solution, but I'm writing this answer to add detail.

Let's start by modeling the real-world object we want to represent. In our case, it's a particle. A particle ought to have a *position*, a *velocity* and an *acceleration*, all of which we can represent using 2D vectors. A reasonable way to store 2D vectors in Haskell is to use the **Linear.V2** module. Next, let's think about nice additional properties we'd like a particle should have, specifically one involved in a firework or explosion. Notice how the particles in a firework burn bright for a time and then just 'fizzle out'? Let's call said time the particle's *lifespan*, and represent it using a **Float**. We can now create an appropriate representation for a **Particle** and a **Cluster** of **Particle**s

```
data Particle = Particle
  { _age          :: Float 
  , _lifespan     :: Float 
  , _position     :: V2 Float
  , _velocity     :: V2 Float
  , _acceleration :: V2 Float }
  deriving ( Show )

type Cluster = [Particle]

makeLenses ''Particle
```

There's an extra field called *age* in our datatype above. The *lifespan* of the particle represents the time for which the particle exists from creation to death, while its *age* represents the time that has passed since the **Particle**'s creation. In other words, a **Particle** should disappear when its *age* exceeds its *lifespan*. Keep that in mind for later.

Next, let's write a function that helps us create a **Particle**. All it does is set the initial *age* to 0 and leave the rest up to additional arguments

```
makeParticle :: Float -> V2 Float -> V2 Float -> V2 Float -> Particle
makeParticle = Particle 0
```

Once this is done, we can write a function that helps us create a **Cluster** of **n** particles

```
makeCluster :: Int -> (Int -> Particle) -> Cluster
makeCluster n particleGen = map particleGen [0..(n - 1)]
```

After that, we create a function that will allow us to advance a **Particle** by **dt** seconds. The function advances the **Particle**'s
*age*, changes its *position* based on its *velocity* and finally changes its *velocity* based on its *acceleration*. In the end, if the *age* of the **Particle** is more than its *lifespan*, we symbolize the deletion of the **Particle** by evaluating to **Nothing** instead of **Just** the changed particle.

```
advanceParticle :: Float -> Particle -> Maybe Particle
advanceParticle dt = hasDecayed . updateVel . updatePos . updateAge
    where
  r2f = realToFrac
  hasDecayed p = if p^.age < p^.lifespan then Just p else Nothing
  updateAge  p = (age      %~ (dt                       +)) p
  updatePos  p = (position %~ (r2f dt * p^.velocity     +)) p
  updateVel  p = (velocity %~ (r2f dt * p^.acceleration +)) p
```

The following function advances a **Cluster**, and gets rid of 'dead' **Particle**s

```
advanceCluster :: Float -> Cluster -> Cluster
advanceCluster dt = catMaybes . map (advanceParticle dt)
```

Now we can move on to the part of the code that has to do with actually drawing particles using **Graphics.Gloss**. We're going to use a **Cluster** to represent the state of the simulation, and so we start with a function that returns a **Cluster** representing the initial state of the program. For a simple animation we're going to simulate a firework, where all the particles start in the same *position*, have the same *lifespan*, radiate out from their central position at regular angles, and are subject to the same *acceleration*

```
initState :: Cluster
initState = makeCluster numParticles particleGen
    where
  numParticles = 10

  particleGen :: Int -> Particle
  particleGen i = 
    makeParticle initLifespan
                 initPosition
                 (initVelMagnitude * V2 (cos angle) (sin angle))  
                 initAcceleration
      where
    fI               = fromIntegral
    angle            = (fI i) * 2 * pi / (fI numParticles)
    initLifespan     = 10
    initPosition     = V2 0 0
    initVelMagnitude = 5
    initAcceleration = V2 0 (-3)
```

Then we write a function to draw a **Cluster** on to the screen

```
drawState :: Cluster -> Picture
drawState = pictures . map drawParticle
    where
  drawParticle :: Particle -> Picture
  drawParticle p = 
    translate (p^.position._x) (p^.position._y)    .
    color     (colorAdjust (p^.age / p^.lifespan)) .
    circleSolid $ circleRadius
      where
    circleRadius  = 3
    colorAdjust a = makeColor 1 0 0 (1 - a)
```

Probably the only non-standard part about this is the **colorAdjust** function. What I was going for here was to color a **Particle** red and when it's created have it not be transparent at all (i.e. alpha value of 1) and keep fading out as its *age* approaches its *lifespan* (i.e. alpha value that keeps approaching 0)

We're almost done! Add a function that updates the **Cluster** to reflect the passage of time

```
stepState :: ViewPort -> Float -> Cluster -> Cluster
stepState _ = advanceCluster
```

Finish up the program by writing a **main** function that ties everything together

```
main :: IO ()
main = 
  simulate (InWindow name (windowWidth, windowHeight) 
                          (windowLocX,  windowLocY))
           bgColor
           stepsPerSec
           initState
           drawState
           stepState
    where
  name             = "Fireworks!"
  windowWidth      = 300
  windowHeight     = 300
  windowLocX       = 30
  windowLocY       = 30 
  stepsPerSec      = 30
  bgColor          = white
```

I hope this helps!